# sending bulk mail with HTML formatted

Tags: powershell

I have a script that will send an email to an employee's manager if thier account is going to expire in the next 30 days. I am pulling each account one by one and
I have been sending them an HTML formatted email with the employee's name and expiration date on behalf of Support to thier manager.

But I don't want to send notification mail one by one to thier manager. for example ,sometimes there may be 30 - 50 users of direct and indirect reports to a manager from Active Directory. So my script will send mail to manager for each expired user. They don't want this.

My question are :
1- How can I send notification mail both  accounts is going to expire in the next 30 days and to their manager bulk instead of one by one ?

e.g  (John, Michael, Andy, Aaron direct reports to theirmanager@domain.com )

```
To: John, Michael, Andy, Aaron
Cc: theirmanager@domain.com
```

2- I want to send HTML formatted mail instead of text message.

message :

`"***The network account for $($name.name) will be expiring on $(($name.AccountExpirationDate).ToShortDateString()), as their manager, could you please confirm they will still be continuing with their role in order to extend their account.***  "`

my desired output :

e.g HTML table formatted

```
name    SamAccountName  AccountExpirationDate   EmployeeID
John    PRD192888     1/31/2021 12:00:00 AM     102928
Michael PRD192876     2/14/2021 12:00:00 AM     102924
Andy    PRD192834     1/12/2021 12:00:00 AM     102934
Aaron   PRD192234     1/31/2021 12:00:00 AM     102679
```

Script :

```
$user = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 | Where-Object { ($_.Enabled -eq $true) -and  ($_.samAccountName -notlike "SCN*") -and ($_.samAccountName -notlike "CVB*") -and  ($_.samAccountName -notlike "PCN*") }

#pulling each account one by one and check to make sure they have a manager assigned. If not those names are piped into a file
foreach ($name in $user){
    If (( Get-ADUser -Identity $name.SamAccountName -Properties *).Manager -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "no manager listed for" $name.name ;
        Add-Content -Path \\path\Folder\No_manager_listed.txt `
        -Value "$(($name.AccountExpirationDate).ToShortDateString())`t $($name.name)"
        }
#accounts with manager are taken one at a time by username to pull out their managers email address.
#this will also send them an email with the employee's name and expiration date on behalf of desktop Support to thier manager
    else { 
    $manager = ( Get-ADUser -Identity $name.SamAccountName -Properties * ).Manager
    $manager_email = (Get-ADUser -Identity $manager -Properties *).mail
    Write-Host "sending notification email to" $manager_email;
    Send-MailMessage -From DesktopSupport@urdomain.com `
    -Subject "Team member account will expire soon" `
    -To $manager_email `
    -Body "***The network account for $($name.name) will be expiring on $(($name.AccountExpirationDate).ToShortDateString()), as their manager, could you please confirm they will still be continuing with their role in order to extend their account.  If they will need an extension, please reply to this email with your approval and we can extend their accounts another 90 days.  If the listed employee is to be transitioned over to a permanent FTE with urdomain, please forward your response to HumanResources@urdomain.com in order to begin the process.  Thank you.***  " `
    -BodyAsHtml -Priority High -SmtpServer postmaster.urdomain.com
            }
}
#this section will email the file that was created from the employees with no manager and email it to desktop support
if (Test-Path \\path\Folder\No_manager_listed.txt){
    Send-MailMessage -From DesktopSupport@urdomain.com `
    -Subject "Expiring accounts with no manager listed report " `
    -To IT-DesktopSupport@urdomain.com `
    -Attachments \\path\Folder\No_manager_listed.txt `
    -Body "****This an automated message. Please review the attachment.***" `
    -BodyAsHtml -Priority High -SmtpServer postmaster.urdomain.com ;
    Start-Sleep -Seconds "10"
    Remove-Item -Path \\path\Folder\\No_manager_listed.txt 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I think users should not know about other users, only managers should see them all.
Because apparently it is important to use the same style (font and font color) with every email you send, I would change your code to something like this:

**Step 1:**

Define a style for the HTML emails so they will all have the same font and colors

```
$style = @"
<style>
    body, table {font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 11pt; color: #1F497D;}
    table {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; color: #000000;}
    th {border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 3px;}
    td {border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px;}
</style>
"@
```

**Step 2:**

Find users  with an account expiration date within the next 30 days

```
# find expiring users and store the AD properties in variable $users
$users = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 -UsersOnly | 
         Where-Object { ($_.Enabled -eq $true) -and  ($_.SamAccountName -notmatch '^(SCN|CVB|PCN)') } |
         ForEach-Object {
            Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties EmailAddress, AccountExpirationDate, Manager
         }
```

> A probably faster (depends on the number of users) alternative to the
> above is to skip the `Search-ADAccount` cmdlet and do:
>
> ```
> $refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(30).Date
> $users = Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -Properties EmailAddress, AccountExpirationDate, Manager | 
>          Where-Object { ($_.AccountExpirationDate -le $refDate) -and  ($_.SamAccountName -notmatch '^(SCN|CVB|PCN)') }
> ```

**Step 3:**

Now that we have the users whose accounts will expire, we can split these up into users without and users with the Manager attribute filled in

```
# create a template to use for mailing the desk support people
# this uses only 1 placeholder to fill in (style)
$mailTemplate = @"
<html><head>{0}</head><body>
This an automated message.<br />Please review the attachment.<br /><br />Thank you.
</body></html>
"@

$noManagerFile = '\\path\Folder\No_manager_listed.csv'
# filter the users that have no manager listed
$unmanagedUsers = @($users | Where-Object { [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Manager) })
if ($unmanagedUsers.Count) {
    Write-Host "There are $($unmanagedUsers.Count) users without manager."
    # output a summary of these users as CSV file to send as attachment to desktop support
    $unmanagedUsers | Select-Object @{Name = 'AccountExpirationDate'; Expression = {$_.AccountExpirationDate.ToShortDateString()}}, Name | 
                      Export-Csv -Path $noManagerFile -NoTypeInformation

    # send an email with attachment for unmanaged users
    $mailParams = @{
        To         = 'IT-DesktopSupport@urdomain.com'
        From       = 'DesktopSupport@urdomain.com'
        Subject    = 'Expiring accounts with no manager listed report'
        Body       = $mailTemplate -f $style
        BodyAsHtml = $true
        Priority   = 'High'
        SmtpServer = 'postmaster.urdomain.com'
        Attachments = $noManagerFile
        # more parameters go here
    }
    Send-MailMessage @mailParams
}
```

**Step 4:**

Next, send an email to every **manager** with all expiring accounts listed

```
# create a template to use for mailing the managers
# this uses 3 placeholders to fill in (style, manager name, and the table of expiring user accounts)
$mailTemplate = @"
<html><head>{0}</head><body>
Dear {1},<br /><br />

The network accounts for the users below will be expiring within the next 30 days.<br />
{2}
<br />
As their manager, could you please confirm they will still be continuing with their role in order to extend their account.<br />
If they will need an extension, please reply to this email with your approval and we can extend their accounts another 90 days.<br /><br />
If the listed employee is to be transitioned over to a permanent FTE with urdomain, please forward your response to 
<a href="mailto:HumanResources@urdomain.com">Human Resources</a> in order to begin the process.  
<br /><br />
Thank you.
</body></html>
"@

# filter out the users that have a Manager listed and group them using the Manager property
# by grouping first, you only need to do Get-ADUser for each manager once.
$managedUsers = $users | Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Manager) } | Group-Object Manager

foreach ($mgrGroup in $managedUsers) {
    # get the manager AD object using the DN from the users Manager attribute to get properties we need from that
    $manager  = Get-ADUser -Identity $mgrGroup.Name -Properties EmailAddress
    $mgrName  = $manager.Name
    $mgrEmail = $manager.EmailAddress

    # if the manager has no email address, report it on screen
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($mgrEmail)) {
        Write-Warning "Could not get email address for manager $($mgrGroup.Name)"
    }
    else {
        # create a table from the user data in the group
        $table = ($mgrGroup.Group | 
                  Select-Object Name, EmailAddress, @{Name = 'ExpiryDate'; Expression = {$_.AccountExpirationDate.ToShortDateString()}} | 
                  ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment) -join [environment]::NewLine

        $mailParams = @{
            To         = $mgrEmail
            From       = 'DesktopSupport@urdomain.com'
            Subject    = 'Expiring Team member accounts'
            Body       = $mailTemplate -f $style, $mgrName, $table  # fill in the placeholders of the mail template
            BodyAsHtml = $true
            Priority   = 'High'
            SmtpServer = 'postmaster.urdomain.com'
            # more parameters go here
        }
        # send this manager an email with a table of all expiring users that report to him/her
        Send-MailMessage @mailParams
    }
}
```

**Step 5:**

Next (if you want) email each user individually about their accounts getting expired. No need for them to know about the other users

```
# create a template to use for mailing the users
# this uses 3 placeholders to fill in (style, first name and expiration date)
$mailTemplate = @"
<html><head>{0}</head><body>
Dear {1},<br /><br />
This is to inform you that your user account will expire on <strong>{2}</strong><br /><br />
DesktopSupport
</body></html>
"@

# send each expiring user that has an email address an email individually
$users | Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.EmailAddress) } | ForEach-Object {
        $mailParams = @{
            To         = $_.EmailAddress
            From       = 'DesktopSupport@urdomain.com'
            Subject    = 'Your user account will expire soon!'
            Body       = $mailTemplate -f $style, $_.GivenName, ('{0:MMMM d, yyyy}' -f $_.AccountExpirationDate)
            BodyAsHtml = $true
            Priority   = 'High'
            SmtpServer = 'postmaster.urdomain.com'
            # more parameters go here
        }
        #Send-MailMessage @mailParams
}
```

**Step 6:**

Look for any 'leftover users' that didn't have an email address.
Just output this as warning onto the console

```
# test if there were users without email address
$noEmail = @($users | Where-Object { [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.EmailAddress) })
if ($noEmail.Count) {
    Write-Warning "These user do not have an email address:"
    $noEmail | Format-Table -Property Name, SamAccountName, AccountExpirationDate
}
```

Comment: thanks but I am getting an error message `Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "ManagerName" because a member with that name already exists. To overwrite the member anyway, add the Force parameter to 
your command.`

Comment: Like you said , I added `Force`  parameter ($manager.Name,$manager.EmailAddress). But no luck.   Also , I checked inside `managedUsers` variable.  its empty. normally, I need 2  AD accounts.

Comment: same issue.(`Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name ....`)   Also , I have been getting `Send-MailMessage : The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.`

Comment: Now , I have checked inside `users` variable.  There is Manager               : CN=John,DC=contoso,DC,=local
ManagerEmail          : {}

Comment: Also , I have checked inside `managedUsers` variable. result :   Count : 2    Name  {}  Group  :  {CN=user1,OU=TEST,DC=contoso,DC=local, CN=user2,OU=TEST,DC=contoso,DC=local}     is it normal ?

Comment: btw ,  I need `$_.ManagerName = $manager.name`    and `$_.ManagerEmail = $manager.EmailAddress` instead of  `Add-Member -MemberType` lines ? 2- I am assuming ,  this script only send notification to manager. I want to add both expired users and manager. it will be Cc expired users inside table

Comment: @Arbelac. I suspect your test users have a non-existing Manager Distinguishedname stored. That is why it fails to retrieve the managers name and email address and as result the script doesn't work. As for the emails: `Managers` get a list of multiple expiring users in one single email. The `Users` only get an email about **their own** account expiration date and don't (shouldn't) see the same of others (privacy). That is what the last `$users | ForEach-Object {..}` does.

Comment: Now ,  I have tried live users instead of test users. Still same issue. I am sure that Manager Distinguishedname stored.   btw I am using with the property dereference operator (.) and the assignment operator (=).  No any issue. But  I am getting `Send-MailMessage : Syntax error in parameters or arguments. The server response was: 5.1.3 Invalid address`

Comment: I think , This is likely happening on your second and subsequent iteration.

Comment: Yes , now its works. But I can't see expired users inside notification mail.  There is `System.Object[]` Dear Manager,

The network accounts for the users below will be expiring within the next 30 days.
System.Object[]   As their manager, could you please confirm they will still be continuing

Comment: btw ,  I noticed that missing `)` for if statement (if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($($manager.EmailAddress))) FYI,

Comment: I am getting Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format..
At line:19 char:9
+         $mailParams = @{
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (<html>
<head>.../body>
</html>:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatError
 
Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'To'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again.

Comment: I want to change only font color of text inside body except table via powershell. But no luck. I have tried a script like below. Just , only color of text. also , I use color property inside CSS. {font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;} My question is : its working properly color property first loop then its not working color:#1F497D for other loops. I want to see color:#1F497D property for each foreach loop. –

Comment: @Arbelac First of all, I don't think you should un-accept my answer to 'get my attention''. I have put a lot of time and effort into this to help you with your request.
However, since now you want to use some other font color in the emails, you decide the answer is no longer any good? Because of that, I have decided **not** to edit again. Also because what you now want has only to do with the way you set up your `$style` CSS where basically the only thing needed is to add `color: #1F497D;` on the `body` and `color: #000000;` on the `table` items.

Comment: like you said , I moved it top of script. bu no luck or I have added after`$managedUsers = $users | Where-Object` .  still issue

Comment: @Arbelac Please read the instructions I gave **carefully**. Not only move the style to the top, but also INSERT it into the appropriate email templates using the `-f` Format operator. Yes, you need a template for all the different email types (every loop needs one)

Comment: You may not have seen my comment. Because of that , I did 'un-accept' action. sorry again for this. thanks to you I did learn new somethings.

Comment: btw , I don't reallay understand. already there is `Body       = $mailTemplate -f $style, $mgrName, $table` . also , what require I do ?

Comment: So , I mean , first loop, I am getting font color `#1F497D` for `The network accounts for the users below .......` but other loops ,    I am not  getting font color `#1F497D` for `The network accounts for the users below .......

Comment: i Theo , I stuck a issue related to smb detect. have you had a chance take a look this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320164/detect-smb1-version-via-powershell-for-all-oses

Comment: @Arbelac I saw it briefly, but it's getting late in my corner of the world..

Answer (score 2):

Powershell has cmdlets for HTML output. Create a collection to hold your table data.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name ConvertTo-Html).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name ConvertTo-Html).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name ConvertTo-Html -Examples
Get-help -Name ConvertTo-Html -Full
Get-help -Name ConvertTo-Html -Online
```

Creating HTML email is also a well-documented thing  with modules in the MS powershellgallery.com

```
 Find-Module -Name '*html*'
# Results
<#
Version  Name              Repository Description                                                                                                                                 
-------  ----              ---------- -----------                                                                                                                                 
0.0.130  PSWriteHTML       PSGallery  Module that allows creating HTML content/reports in a easy way.                                                                             
2.2.2    MarkdownToHtml    PSGallery  Highly configurable markdown to HTML conversion using customizable templates....                                                            
0.1.7    PowerHTML         PSGallery  Provides a wrapper for HTML Agility Pack for use where the IE HTML ...
1.4.1.2  ReportHTML        PSGallery  A powerful module for creating HTML reports within PowerShell no HTML coding required....
...
#>
```

Or using Style/CSS. Many examples are on SO:

> [PowerShell Display Table In HTML Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263538/powershell-display-table-in-html-email)

...and all over the web.

> ['PowerShell html table email'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20html%20table%20email%27&t=h_&ia=web)

***Example hit(s)***

> [How to Send SMTP Email Using PowerShell (Part 4)](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/powershell-html-email-formatting)
>
> [Sending HTML emails with PowerShell and zero HTML knowledge required](https://evotec.xyz/sending-html-emails-with-powershell-and-zero-html-knowledge-required)

***Example:***

```
$disks = GET-WMIOBJECT win32_logicaldisk -filter "DriveType='3'"

foreach($disk in $disks)
{
    $DriveLetter = $disk.DeviceID;
    $SizeGB      = $disk.Size / 1GB -as [int]
    $FreeSpaceGB = $disk.FreeSpace / 1GB -as [int]
    $PercentFree = [math]::Round((1- ($freeSpaceGB/ $sizeGB)) * 100)

    $dataRow = "
    </tr>
        <td>$DriveLetter</td>
        <td>$SizeGB GB</td>
        <td>$FreeSpaceGB GB</td>
        <td>$PercentFree %</td>
    </tr>
    "
    $diskreport += $datarow
}

$report = "<html>
<style>
    {font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt;}
    TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; font-size:13pt;}
    TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; color: #000000;}
    TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
</style>
<h2>Server Space Report</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Volume</th>
        <th>Total Space</th>
        <th>Free Space</th>
        <th>Percent Full</th>
    </tr>
$diskreport
</table>
<tr>
"


$sendMailMessageSplat = @{
    From              = 'ServerReport@test.com'
    To                = 'luke@test.com'
    Subject           = "Server Disk Space Report"
    Body              = $report
    SmtpServer        = 'mysmtpserver.com'
}
Send-MailMessage @sendMailMessageSplat
```