# Detect SMB1 version via powershell for all OSes

Tags: powershell

My workflow:

- check if server is pingable
- find if they are domain connected or not and perform a task accordingly. if Operating system 2012 and/or R2 ,2016 or 2019 newer OSes then I will run Get-SmbServerConfiguration cmdlet.  if machine is not a part of default domain then `else` block will run.
- if Operating system 2003 or 2008 oldest OSes then I will run Get-Wmi cmdlet.  if machine is not a part of default domain then `else` block will run.

Finally , I will concentanate `$results` variable.

My question is :

1- How can we get remotely regedit value for 2003 or 2008 oldest OSes IS NOT a part of default domain insie else block?

Also ,  Condition will be like below.

```
 if SMB1 value is "0" then result will be `false`
 if SMB1 value is "1" then result will be `true`
 if SMB1 value is not exist then result will be `not exist value`
```

2-  How can I create object properties $SMBAudit variable ? because , I will concentanate all outputs inside $results variable.

```
$reg = [wmiclass]"\\$computer\root\default:StdRegProv"
$SMBAudit = $reg.GetStringValue($basekey, $subkey, $value).sValue
```

My desired output :

```
Computername,SMB1Enabled
Host01,True
Host02,False
```

I will write so far a script like below. but I am stucking somethings.

Script :

```
# Computer List
$allComputers = Get-Content .\path\to\computers.txt

read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\mysecurestring_domain.txt

read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\mysecurestring_local.txt

# Create empty array of results
$Results = @()

# Loop through computers
foreach($computer in $allComputers) {

    
        # check if server is pingable before running the query on the server
        if (Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {  

            Write-Host "`n`n$computer is online!" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
            
        }
        if(Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq $computer -and OperatingSystem -notlike '*Windows*Server*2003*' -and OperatingSystem -notlike '*Windows*Server*2008*'})
            {
        #"machine $_ is a part of default domain"
            # The command we want to run
            
            $username = "domain01\admin01"
$password = Get-Content 'C:\mysecurestring_domain.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
    $SMB = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB1Protocol }
    
    # Create properties
    $Properties = @{
        # Populate the properties "Computername" and "SMB1Enabled" with variables
        Computername = $Computer
        SMB1Enabled = $SMB.EnableSMB1Protocol

    }
    # Add the properties to the result for each object
    $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
        
        
        }
        else
        {
        #"machine $_ IS NOT a part of default domain"
        
                    $username = "localadmin01"
$password = Get-Content 'C:\mysecurestring_local.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
            $SMB = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB1Protocol }
    
    # Create properties
    $Properties = @{
        # Populate the properties "Computername" and "SMB1Enabled" with variables
        Computername = $Computer
        SMB1Enabled = $SMB.EnableSMB1Protocol

    }
    # Add the properties to the result for each object
    $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
        
        
        
        }
        
        # Oldest OSes

        if(Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq $computer -and OperatingSystem -notlike '*Windows*Server*2012*' -and OperatingSystem -notlike '*Windows*Server*2016*' -and OperatingSystem -notlike '*Windows*Server*2019*'})
            {
        #"machine $_ is a part of default domain"
            # The command we want to run
          <# HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (2147483648 (0x80000000))
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER (2147483649 (0x80000001))
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (2147483650 (0x80000002))
 HKEY_USERS (2147483651 (0x80000003))
 HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG (2147483653 (0x80000005))
 #>
 
        $basekey  = [uint32]'0x80000002'
$subkey   = 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters'
$value    = 'SMB1'

$reg = [wmiclass]"\\$computer\root\default:StdRegProv"
$SMBAudit = $reg.GetStringValue($basekey, $subkey, $value).sValue


        
        
        }
        else
        {
        #"machine $_ IS NOT a part of default domain"

        




}

# Output
$Results | Select-Object Computername, SMB1Enabled | Out-File -Filepath c:\temp\smb1-computers.txt
```

Comment: As for this, `How can we get remotely regedit value for 2003 or 2008 oldest OSes IS NOT a part of default domain`, this called Workgroup mode remoting. There are many MSDocs, 3rdP articles, blogs, Youtube videos on how to set that up and use it. Otherwise, the MS SysInternals tool, psexec, to hit remote machines that you have permission/authority to hit and do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over complicating this and although not tested by me, you could try this:

```
# Computer List
$allComputers = Get-Content '.\path\to\computers.txt'

# get credentials for domain-joined machines and for local machines
$domainCred = Get-Credential -UserName "domain01\admin01" -Message "Please enter the DOMAIN password"
$localCred  = Get-Credential -UserName "localadmin01" -Message "Please enter the LOCAL password"

# loop through the list of computers and collect output in variable $Results
$Results = foreach($computer in $allComputers) {
    # check if server is pingable before running the query on the server
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {  
        Write-Host "$computer is online!" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black

        $server = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$computer'" -Properties OperatingSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        # if domain joined, use $domainCred, otherwise $localCred
        if ($server) { 
            $cred    = $domainCred
            $version = ([regex]'Windows Server (\d+)').Match($server.OperatingSystem).Groups[1].Value
        } 
        else { 
            $cred    = $localCred
            $info    = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
            $version = ([regex]'Windows Server (\d+)').Match($info.Caption).Groups[1].Value
        }
        if ($version -eq '2003') {
            # try reading the registry
            try {
                $RegBase = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Computer)
                $RegKey  = $RegBase.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters")
                $SMB     = $RegKey.GetValue("SMB1")
                [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; SMB1Enabled = ($null -eq $SMB -or [int]$SMB -eq 1) }
            }
            catch {
                [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; SMB1Enabled = 'Could not read Remote Registry' }
            }
            finally {
                if ($RegBase) { $RegBase.Close() }
                if ($RegKey)  { $RegKey.Close() }
            }
        }
        elseif ($version -eq '2008') {
            # Older OS
            try {
                # try via WinRM
                $SMB = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
                            Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters' -Name SMB1
                       } -ErrorAction Stop
                # output an object
                [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; SMB1Enabled = ($null -eq $SMB -or [int]$SMB -eq 1) }
            }
            catch {
                # try reading the registry
                try {
                    $RegBase = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Computer)
                    $RegKey  = $RegBase.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters")
                    $SMB     = $RegKey.GetValue("SMB1")
                    [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; SMB1Enabled = ($null -eq $SMB -or [int]$SMB -eq 1) }
                }
                catch {
                    [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; SMB1Enabled = 'Could not read Remote Registry' }
                }
                finally {
                    if ($RegBase) { $RegBase.Close() }
                    if ($RegKey)  { $RegKey.Close() }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            # Newer OS
            $SMB = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select-Object EnableSMB1Protocol }
            # output an object
            [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; SMB1Enabled = $SMB.EnableSMB1Protocol }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer $computer is off-line"
        # output an object anyway, so that in the CSV it is known that the computer didn't ping
        [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; SMB1Enabled = 'Off-Line' }
    }
}

# Output on screen
$Results | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Output to CSV file
$Results | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\smb1-computers.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Comment: thanks but I am assuming , there is problem inside regex.      because Get-ADcomputer -> Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard  but  its working `Get-SmbServerConfiguration blah `   instead of `Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:`   this regex all 2003 and / or 2008 combination catching ?

Comment: same still issue , Get-ADcomputer -> for Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard but its working Get-SmbServerConfiguration blah  instead of Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:  ,error message : `The term 'Get-SmbServerConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`` So  normally , Get-ItemProperty cmdlet will run for 2008 and / or 2003 server. So  there is no  cmdlet Get-SMB  for 2003 , 2008.

Comment: btw ,  as you know  , 2003 server can support PowerShell 1.0 and doesn't have PowerShell remoting capability. My lastly question is : Lets say , if operating system is 2003 then I want to run `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Computer)`.  how can I do that ?  how can I integrate your script ? `  $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Computer.Name)$RegKey =$Reg.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\LanmanServer\\Parameters")$SMBAudit = $RegKey.GetValue("SMB1")` ,

Comment: SMB1 value is "0" then result will be `false` SMB1 value is "1" then result will be `true`  SMB1 value is not exist then result will be `true`

Comment: thanks btw ,  Windows 2008 condition will be same as 2003. SMB1 value is "0" then result will be false SMB1 value is "1" then result will be true SMB1 value is not exist then result will be true

Comment: it works very well. lastly , I noticed something. I can't reach some machines (2018 server) via WinRM port.  my question is : lets say , if script can't reach to the 2008 machines  via WinRM port (error message: `Connecting to remote server aksa_antrepo1 failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination
specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the
WS-Managem....`) then I want to get SMB1 value via `OpenRemoteBaseKey` as alternative.

Comment: note : winrm 5985, and the default HTTPS port is 5986.

Comment: btw , I have updated my question.  (LAST UPDATE) is it true for 2008 block script?

Comment: @Arbelac I'll try to look at it tomorrow. At first glance, set `-ErrorAction Stop` on the `Invoke-Command` and in the catch block do the registry method for 2008 servers

Comment: is there any comment ?

Comment: @Arbelac I have added the 'escape' to use Remote Registry in the 2008 block now. Question: Why do you still run these old OSes and why do you not allow WinRM on servers that _could_ be reached that way? [How to Enable WinRM on Windows Servers & Clients](https://support.infrasightlabs.com/article/how-to-enable-winrm-on-windows-servers-clients/) ?

Comment: Hi Theo ,  I need your help too.  :)   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477453/exchange-distribution-group-restriction-nested-group-report-issue-via-poershell

Comment: have you had a chance take a look this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477453/exchange-distribution-group-restriction-nested-group-report-issue-via-poershell

Comment: @Arbelac yep, but needs some thinking over.. Hopefully I'll post an answer soon, but it is going to take me a while I think. Could very well be someone else will respond sooner.